# extracting data from nc files using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, netcdf

I am trying to extract values of some parameters from an `nc` file, but my code doesn't work for the `slp` parameter, though it works for the other parameters.  The code is showing me negative values for `slp` which means the importing of the data is not correct.

I used this script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('agg')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy.io import netcdf_file as nc
from pylab import *

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from glob import glob


files1 = glob('n1*nc')
files1.sort()
MVAL1 = -32767
for item in files1:
  clf()
  f1 = nc(item)
  times=f1.variables['time'] 
  lon = f1.variables['longitude'].data
  lat = f1.variables['latitude'].data
  slp = f1.variables['msl'].data   
  # to convert to hpa
  slp = slp*0.01
  dims = slp.shape                   
  print slp.shape, np.max(slp), np.min(slp)
```

The results are

```
(73, 121) 327.67 -327.66
```

while when I check it in `Panoply` the min and max values are different.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't really see what this question has to do with matplotlib. Could you show your imports please?

Comment: the nc file has data for the mean sea level pressure which has minimum value of 995 and maximum of 1020 , this is according to another program used to open nc files , but when i used python to extract and plot the same parameter according to the previous script it is giving me minimum of -327.66 and maximum of 327.66 which is totaly wrong.it means the  line                                                              slp = f1.variables['msl'].data     is not importing the values in correct way .

Comment: OK... but you still haven't shown your import statements yet. You would have a much better chance at getting a useful answer if you could upload the file in question as well.

Comment: it is as follows                                                                                   import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl 
mpl.use('agg')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy.io import netcdf_file as nc
from pylab import *
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 
from glob import glob
thanks a lot

Comment: You should edit your question to add those details rather than putting them in the comments

Comment: `f1 = nc(item, version=2)` maybe they are version 2 netcdf

Comment: the script I have posted above is working for the other parameters like the u and v wind , but it doesnt work for the msl !!!! , I tried your suggestion but its not working also . thanks

Comment: without seeing the original data it's hard for us to verify what sort of error has occurred -- we can't even verify *that* an error has occurred.

Comment: is it true that `slp` *cannot* be negative, in *any* of the files?  is that the giveaway that an error has occurred?

Comment: try comparing the import of *one* file to the import of *the same* file in `panoply`, instead of comparing this script -- which imports all files -- to `panoply`.

Comment: the msl variable is short not float , I think the wrong thing is coming from this line        
    var = np.ma.masked_equal(var, MVAL1)       where MVAL1 = -32767s which represents the missing value , how to deal with short variables ?

Comment: float longitude(longitude) ;
                longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
                longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
        
               short msl(time, latitude, longitude) ;
                msl:scale_factor = 0.0402468985091481 ;
                msl:add_offset = 100400.104876551 ;
                msl:_FillValue = -32767s ;
                msl:missing_value = -32767s ;
                msl:units = "Pa" ;
                msl:long_name = "Mean sea level pressure" ;
                msl:standard_name = "air_pressure_at_sea_level" ;

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that Panoply is automatically applying the `scale_factor` and `add_offset` attributes to the `short` data and presenting the results to you as floats in the physical units (Pa).  By default `scipi.io` does not apply those attributes, so you'll need to do it manually:

```
slp = f1.variables['msl']
fslp = slp[:]*slp.scale_factor + slp.add_offset
```

In your case the possible range of the data will be approximately -32766*scale + offset = 99081. Pa to 32767*scale + offset = 101718. Pa.

It's quite common for higher level, convention aware packages (e.g., Panoply, Ferret) to apply these packing attributes automatically and for lower level interfaces (e.g., Scipy.IO) to leave it to the user.  You might consider using the [NetCDF4 Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4/1.1.6) instead, which handles packing and fill values automatically.

Comment: I tried the suggested lines but I got this                                   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'scale_factor'
do I have to set the values of the offset ?  Thanks

Comment: I thought that might happen.  Look at the definition of my `slp` variable; it's a handle for the whole netCDF variable (data+metadata) rather than just the Numpy array containing the data, which is what you have in your code.  Also, the `slp[:]` is a shorthand for `slp.data`.

Comment: what if I want to select many specific time for the variables,(i.e times=f1.variables['time'][4] ),this works for the four timestep , but i need to choose for example 1,2,4 , how can I set the intervals ?

Comment: @SamaK You should really open that as a different question, but read this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays